# Android .axml Design failing to load

Tags: android, sdk, xamarin

When every I try to load any .axml file this error comes up (below pic). I have ruled out the android SDK as I re-downloaded it, so i think this is a problem with xamarin. If you need more info just ask for it and I will supply it.
[image: Error]